# When adding elements and buttons to a div, how can each button remove itself?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a script that can add paragraphs to a div. These paragraphs have some text and a delete button in them. This delete button should be able to delete the paragraph its in including its text (so delete the whole paragraph), but it doesn't.

```js
var elementCounter2 = 0;

function addElement2() {
  elementCounter2++;
  var p = document.createElement("p");
  var node = document.createTextNode("This is element number " + elementCounter2);
  p.setAttribute("id", "p" + elementCounter2);
  p.appendChild(node);
  p.innerHTML += ' <button id="del' + elementCounter2 + '" onclick="deleteElement2();">Delete this element.</button>';
  document.getElementById("elements2").appendChild(p);
}

function deleteElement2() {
  var p = document.getElementById("p" + elementCounter2);
  var btn = document.getElementById("del" + elementCounter2);

  //Button sees its own id and look for the corresponding p id, then deletes the paragraph.
}
```

```css
.borderful {
  border: solid 1px black;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="borderful">
  <p>Here is the second part</p>
  <p>You can add elements here.</p>
  <p>You can delete these aswell but differntly.</p>
  <button onclick="addElement2();">Add an element.</button>
  <div id="elements2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Multiple ways to do this; using your existing code you use `onclick="deleteElement2(this);"` and `function deleteElement2(btn)` to get the button. Or do this: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/fvh17gd8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can setup an event listener on each newly created paragraph (ditching the inline code) and forget about the counter (kept here to show the code working)

```js
var elementCounter2 = 0;

function addElement2() {
  elementCounter2++;
  var p = document.createElement("p");
  var node = document.createTextNode("This is element number " + elementCounter2);
  p.setAttribute("id", "p" + elementCounter2);
  p.appendChild(node);
  p.innerHTML += ' <button>Delete this element.</button>';
  document.getElementById("elements2").appendChild(p);
  var el = document.getElementById("p" + elementCounter2);
  el.addEventListener("click", deleteElement2, false);
}

function deleteElement2() {
  this.remove()
}
```

```css
.borderful {
  border: solid 1px black;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="borderful">
  <p>Here is the second part</p>
  <p>You can add elements here.</p>
  <p>You can delete these aswell but differntly.</p>
  <button onclick="addElement2();">Add an element.</button>
  <div id="elements2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution. Though i have only been doing javascript for 2 weeks now and i havnt quite gotten to eventlisteners yet so ill write it down for later.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```js
var elementCounter2 = 0;

function addElement2() {
  elementCounter2++;
  var p = document.createElement("p");
  var node = document.createTextNode("This is element number " + elementCounter2);
  p.setAttribute("id", "p" + elementCounter2);
  p.appendChild(node);
  p.innerHTML += ' <button id="del' + elementCounter2 + '" onclick="deleteElement2(this);">Delete this element.</button>';
  document.getElementById("elements2").appendChild(p);
}

function deleteElement2(caller) { 
  // caller = button
  document.getElementById("del" + caller.id.substr(3)).parentNode.remove();
}
```

```css
.borderful {
  border: solid 1px black;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="borderful">
  <p>Here is the second part</p>
  <p>You can add elements here.</p>
  <p>You can delete these aswell but differntly.</p>
  <button onclick="addElement2();">Add an element.</button>
  <div id="elements2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution, this is probably how i would have most likely solved it if i searched and thought about it for longer then i have.

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach is referring to the paragraph as a parent element instead of worrying how to reference it directly.

```
    function deleteElement2() {
        this.parentElement.remove();
    }
```

However, adding the button as

> `p.innerHTML += ' <button id="del'+ elementCounter2 +'" onclick="deleteElement2();">Delete this element.</button>';`

Is not a good practice since you are adding HTML element in Javascript, when you can go about doing this in Javascript only.

To learn more about your original question or how to do this in JS, refer to this very similar example given by CS50W lecture on YouTube: https://youtu.be/ZRV7JCXAFTs?t=2486

Comment: Thank you for sharing this creator with me, i know the way im putting the button in the code is wrong but document.getElementById().innerHTML is just the way my school taught me how to change stuff with javascript. Im trying to learn the languague for real for 2 weeks now so excuse me for beginnersfaults like that one :) (ive just started on learning the DOM 2 days ago).